# Android L - EMM/MDM - Launching Managed app from Unmanaged app

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been trying the Android MDM sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicManagedProfile and there are couple of questions that I am not clear on,

1. Why is there a separate managed and unmanaged version for the profile-owner app? I am not sure how to design the application flow, like in my app assume I provide two functionalities, one is to browse some SharePoint sites and save files to disk and the second is to provision/manage apps which is controlled by the admin (from an admin console).
   Because there are two versions of my application once user enables the profile, user can click on any of the icons. If user clicks on the unmanaged version then I am not able to perform any app-provisioning related tasks and have to ask the user to launch the managed version to continue.
   In the managed version if user wants to access any of his data, then I have to use the file-provider to access app's data which was downloaded via unmanaged version.
   So am not sure if the new API's requires the user to be forced to use the managed version only?
2. Is there a way to launch the managed version of the app from the unmanaged version of the same application which is a profile owner and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Basic Managed Profile in Android Lollipop is to separate the corporate data versus personal data. You can get an overview of this on this [website.](http://www.android.com/it/preview/) Most of the EMM features are a reflection of Samsung Knox.

There is a way to identify which of your applications are under a managed profile or personal profile; [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getUserBadgedIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.os.UserHandle))

The new APIs allow a given device to have managed and personal apps to coexist.
For example, you can have a managed gmail app (configured for corporate use) and another gmail app (for your own account).

To answer your second question, if your app is a device owner app, you can then use the device owner apis to launch a given app.